# Android XML: Centering a Textview in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have this XML code which I want to use as a foundation for my loading screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/loading">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading_message"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="LOADING..." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

which is in main_loading.xml and the TextView should clearly be centered, and in the Eclipse XML preview, it is (so all is well and good, for now).

However, I am using this XML alongside another so I am using:

```
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.llid);
    mainLayout.removeAllViews();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    mainLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_loading, null));
```

To swap between XMLs, which all works perfectly fine on the emulator, except the centering of the Textview (it stays unaligned -top left). Why is this? How can I center something using the above inflater/layout code?

### Edit

My other XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:id="@+id/llid">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="Login" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit_message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem appears to be with RelativeLayout `llid`. It is either set to `wrap_content` or its `gravity` isn't centered. Could you post `llid`'s XML?

Comment: I do agree with @Sam . Another thing you could try to check if it's the case is to set main_loading background to a color different from llid's one in order to see how main_loading is placed inside its parent.

Comment: Swapping layouts in a single activity seems strange to me. Have you considered using fragments instead?

Comment: @Sam, yes llid is not centered (it's wrap_content) although I want one centered and one not centered, is this possible with inflater?

Comment: You can do anything with a LayoutInflater that you can do with straight XML, the problem that you are seeing is that you have centered a layout inside of an offset layout... Without seeing more code all I can suggest is dividing your layout: to center the layout you want centered; while leaving the layout you want offset, offset...

Comment: By dividing do you mean a different activity, not too keen on those. And okay i've edited OP to show other xml file...